# Why is the length of a value sometimes the width of the column instead of the length of the string?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Consider the following SQL

```
DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @t AS TABLE(
    field  char(32),
    len1   int,
    nfield nchar(32),
    nlen1  int,
    vfield varchar(32),
    vlen1  int
);

SET @JSON = '[
    { "Field" : "abcd" }
]'
INSERT INTO @t
SELECT
    Field      as field,
    Len(Field) as len1,
    Field      as nfield,
    Len(Field) as nlen1,
    Field      as vfield,
    Len(Field) as vlen1
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)
WITH ( Field nchar(32) );

INSERT INTO @t ( field , len1       ,nfield, nlen1      ,vfield, vlen1      )
VALUES         ( 'efgh', len('efgh'),'efgh', len('efgh'),'efgh', len('efgh'))

SELECT
    field,
    len1,
    len(field)  as len2,
    nlen1,
    len(nfield) as nlen2,
    vlen1,
    len(vfield) as vlen2
FROM @t;
```

which outputs

```
field  len1  len2  nlen1  nlen2  vlen1  vlen2
------ ----- ----- ------ ------ ------ ------
abcd   4     4     4      32     4      4
efgh   4     4     4      4      4      4
```

The length of the value originating from JSON in the `nchar(32)` field is 32 while all others are the length of the string.  This was a surprise to me so I'm looking for an underlying explanation.

What is happening that this one case of the 12 has a different result?

Answer (score 6):

Much simpler repro:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(f1 char(32), f2 nchar(32));

INSERT @t SELECT f AS f1, f AS f2 FROM OPENJSON('[
    { "f" : "abcd" }
]') WITH (f nchar(32));

SELECT f1, f2, f1l = LEN(f1), f2l = LEN(f2) FROM @t;
```

Output:

| f1 | f2 | f1l | f2l |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | abcd | 4 | 32 |

I don't quite know what's going on here, but Hannah may be onto something about data type / implicit conversion while data is being pulled from JSON and inserted into the table, and going through who knows how many translations in the inner bowels of JSON-land.

I did notice that when I ran this query in Azure Data Studio, the grid output looked the *opposite* of what I would have expected, e.g. with a length of 4 I expected the left column to be *skinny*, and the right column to be wide:

> [image: Strange output in Azure Data Studio]

Of course `LEN()` doesn't really tell you how wide a string is when there are trailing spaces, since they are ignored.

If I copy the contents of those cells, it is a bit clearer what's going on (just not *why*). On the left, there are actually 32 characters. So why doesn't it do that on the right? Well, that string is padded with something that is definitely *not* spaces:

> [image: Even stranger output in Azure Data Studio]

Other notes:

- `DATALENGTH()` works as expected (32 on the left, 64 on the right).
- Passing it through metadata discovery functions didn't yield anything funny or give any clues about the source of those non-printing characters:

  ```
    SELECT name, system_type_name
    FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
    (N'DECLARE @t TABLE(f1 char(32), f2 nchar(32));

    INSERT @t SELECT f AS f1, f AS f2 FROM OPENJSON(''[
        { "f" : "abcd" }
    ]'') WITH (f nchar(32));

    SELECT f1, f2 FROM @t;', NULL, 0);
  ```

  | name | system_type_name |
  | --- | --- |
  | f1 | char(32) |
  | f2 | nchar(32) |

So then I went back and decided to check the right-most character of each string, and sure enough, in one case it's a space (`char(32)`), and in the other it's a terminator (`nchar(0)`):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(f1 char(32), f2 nchar(32));

INSERT @t SELECT f AS f1, f AS f2 FROM OPENJSON('[
    { "f" : "abcd" }
]') WITH (f nchar(32));

SELECT f1, f2, ASCII(RIGHT(f1,1)),UNICODE(RIGHT(f2,1)) FROM @t;
```

| f1 | f2 | - | - |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | abcd | 32 | 0 |

So, I don't know why JSON is producing this artifact, but you can work around it using `DATALENGTH` instead of `LEN`, or perhaps by using `nvarchar` instead of `nchar` (which is arguably a better choice for strings that will obviously vary in length anyway).

Comment: My guess is a bug in SQL Server, the C/C++ code (?) not removing the null termination of the string before exposing it at the SQL level. I have worked with data where the client app developers did the same and it drove my string manipulation in T-SQL nuts.

Comment: Strings come in different flavors. Fixed length, nul terminated, and [both](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/). Looking at them with something that doesn't know which kind to assume can have interesting results.

Answer (score 5):

#### Example

```
DECLARE @t table (f nchar(5) NOT NULL);

INSERT @t (f)
SELECT OJ.f 
FROM OPENJSON(N'[{ "f" : "abcd" }]')
    WITH (f nchar(5)) AS OJ;

SELECT 
    T.f,
    len_f = LEN(T.f),
    dl_f = DATALENGTH(T.f),
    bin_f = CONVERT(varbinary(10), f) 
FROM @t AS T;
```

| f | len_f | dl_f | bin_f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 5 | 10 | 0x61006200630064000000 |

#### Cause

When the data type of the JSON element exactly matches the target table, SQL Server incorrectly assumes no padding is needed.

In the example above, the declared type is `nchar(5)` but the source string is only 4 characters. Despite the type match, the string should still be padded with a space (`ANSI_PADDING` is always on for `nchar`).

The fact it appears padded with zeroes is likely due to buffer overflow protection and initializing the buffer with zeroes. It could also conceivably be erroneous padding as would be appropriate for binary values.

In any case, it is a product defect.

#### Workarounds

Either ensure the strings in the JSON match the declared type without the need for padding or cast the returned column to a slightly larger type so SQL Server applies the usual padding and truncation rules.

```
DECLARE @t table (f nchar(5) NOT NULL);

INSERT @t (f)
SELECT CONVERT(nchar(6), OJ.f) -- Workaround
FROM OPENJSON(N'[{ "f" : "abcd" }]')
    WITH (f nchar(5)) AS OJ;

SELECT 
    T.f,
    len_f = LEN(T.f),
    dl_f = DATALENGTH(T.f),
    bin_f = CONVERT(varbinary(10), f) 
FROM @t AS T;
```

| f | len_f | dl_f | bin_f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 4 | 10 | 0x61006200630064002000 |

You could also use `nvarchar(5)` in the `WITH` clause.